How is lowering in vapour pressure a colligative property?
Imagine we have two containers: A and B. Both contain equal amounts of water and we add (say 50) molecules of sucrose and 50 molecules of glucose in containers A and B respectively.
Now, the typical explanation as to why vapour pressure lowers when we had non volatile and non electrolyte solutes is that solute particles occupy some space on the surface which lowers the surface for evaporation and consequently, the vapour pressure lowers.
But in the thought experiment I presented, the two molecules have two different sizes and therefore sucrose (being a larger molecules) should occupy greater space at the surface so we should expect vapour pressure to lower by greater amount in this case. But we also define lowering in vapour pressure as a colligative property so it should be independent of nature of solutes.
Can you explain, to me, how is it a colligative property in the light of this thought experiment?

Well, the 'typical explanation' is utter nonsense. It is equivalent to saying the equilibrium vapor pressure over a narrow-necked flask is less that over a punch bowl. Colligative properties are all about the interactions between the various components of the solution and how those impact the free energies of the components.

Hey Jon, can you elaborate? Possibly, give the correct explanation?

It comes down to the activity of water lowered by the same amount, no matter what you add. This is determined by the mole fraction of water, not the mass fraction. It is a bit like mixtures of ideal gases - the masses don't matter, and the type of molecule (mass, shape, etc) doesn't matter because they don't interact in the gas phase. Why it works for liquids is less obvious (i.e. why ideal-diluted solutions exist).

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/64178/reasons-for-existence-of-eutectic-point-for-alloy-systems/71925#71925 and links therein may help. Adding solute changes the free energy of both solvent and solute.

See also https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/182183/35806
