# Diffusion between phases based on chemical potential

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, phase

[image]

How is the concept of diagram(b) different from that of (e) and (d) from (f)?Someone told me in one of my earlier posts ([Why will A atoms diffuse from β phase to α phase and B atoms from α phase to β phase?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/118244/why-will-a-atoms-diffuse-from-%ce%b2-phase-to-%ce%b1-phase-and-b-atoms-from-%ce%b1-phase-to-%ce%b2-p)) that he is used to see graphs with two minimia but somewhere where we had two phase separately named as $G^{\alpha}$ and $G^{\beta}$ vs the composition curve he seemed something that he saw for the very first time. Please help me to differentiate the two of them and also answer the question that I have in this post.

Comment: (a)(b) is normal diffusion producing one phase of A and B mixed (c)(d) is phase separation. Look at the way the arrows point.

Comment: @porphyrin How are we so sure that this is not a single phase?And how did u conclude the fact of diffusion and phase separation.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/75035/common-tangent-construction/75038#75038 May help.

Comment: @JonCuster Are you saying that (d) and (f) is the same thing?

Comment: I have no idea what they are trying to represent in (f). But, the stable configuration would be similar for (d) and (f), yes.

Comment: The logic is similar somewhat to the stable and unstable equlibrium diagram that we had in physics isn't it?@JonCuster

Comment: Looking at (c) the phases must separate as B is transferred into the B rich region and similarly for A. So this is phase separation driven by enthalpy dominating free energy change. Normal diffusion (a) occurs the other way round ( diffusion out of high concentration region) driven by entropy.

Comment: If your system refers to two partially miscible liquids  the region between the two minima in (d) is where two phases exist, outside this region one phase exists, i.e. at low A or high B.

Comment: @porphyrin What about (b) is it the same phase throughout.I do not see any inflection point.So is there any region where two phases may coexist?

Comment: yes (b) is fully miscible one phase all proportions, e.g. benzene-toluene.